# Why did the Capitol bomb District 13?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-mockingjay-1

In The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 1 (2014), they never explained why the capital bombed them originally. Why did the capital bomb district 13 before the movie started?

> "I was always told there was nothing left of 13."

and

> "The capital bombed the surface to rubble, but we're military so we learned to survive down here."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was destroyed during the First Rebellion when the united districts of Panem rebelled against the Capitol's oppressive rule.

> Near the end of the war, District 13 trained nuclear missiles on the
>   Capitol, hoping to destroy the Capitol even if the result was mutually
>   assured destruction. However, District 13 set up a secret deal with
>   the Capitol - they would withdraw their forces from the war and
>   present the illusion that Capitol bombers equipped with Toxic bombs
>   destroyed District 13. 13 withdrew and rebuilt their district
>   underground. The Capitol's bombers then destroyed the district on the
>   surface. Without 13's aid, the remaining rebel forces were put down by
>   the Capitol.

The Hunger Games commemorate the Capitol's victory in this war and serve to remind the citizens of Panem of the futility of rebellion.

Sources:
http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Days